# Show that $|X^G|\equiv |X| \bmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Question:When a finite group $G$ acts on a finite set $X$, $X^G$ is defined as
$$ X^G=\{x\in X \mid \forall g\in G,~~gx=x \} $$
If $|G|$ is power of $p$ ($p$ is a prime number), show that 
$$ |X^G|\equiv |X| \mod p$$
where $|A|$ is number of elements of $A$.

Comment: It looks like you've just copied your homework onto this site for people to solve for you. This is not an appropriate use of the website and the question is likely to be closed. See [How to ask a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1804/437127) and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/437127).

Comment: This is a question I found on the internet and this is not my homework. But I can't prove that. Should I edit something?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't phrase a question here in the kind of language that is suitable for assigning homework.

Comment: If you look at the advice how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), including the source of the problem would be a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using orbit-stabilizer theorem we have,
$X= X^G \bigcup_{x \notin X^G} \mathbb{O}_x$.
Also, this theorems says (In finite setup)
$\#\mathbb{O}_x \mid \#G $. Since $G$ is $p$-group and $\#\mathbb{O}_x \neq 1$,
Implies $\#\mathbb{O}_x $ is $p$-powers. hence divisible by $p$. This implies your result.